# Any two curves over k homeomorphic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, books

Why are two curves over a field k homeomorphic?

I have been able to prove that any variety of positive dimension over a field k has the same cardinality as k.

Comment: Can you give a simple description of the Zariski topology of a curve?

Comment: Rather than create new tags "algebraic" and "geometry" I fixed the tagging


Comment: I reverted the "faux-delete" that the OP attempted

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alright I'll just answer so that I can get enough "reputation" to be able to comment and ask for a question to be closed because it belongs in other sites (see the faq).

A bijection between two topological spaces $f:X \rightarrow Y$ where open sets are complements of finite sets is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to MO.